# How to make a separate view if there is no item in Dart Flutter listTile?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application:

[image]

The `listTile` items here come from the database.

**Codes:**

```
Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 40),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 15,),
                Text("Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),),
                Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.black,),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Solved Tests:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: listUpload(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      late List<String?> items;
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      items = [];
                      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                        snapshot.hasData) {
                      items = snapshot.data as List<String?>;
                      } else {
                        items = [];
                      }
                      return Scrollbar(
                        isAlwaysShown: true,
                        controller: _scrollContreller,
                        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          controller: _scrollContreller,
                          itemCount: items.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  
                                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    items[index].toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                  })),
                ),
```

---

**Calling items from database:**

```
  dynamic listUpload() async {
    final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final getTests = prefences.getStringList("tests"); // get item
    debugPrint(getTests.toString());
    return Future.value(getTests);
  }
```

---

If there is no data in the database, I want the `listTile` to say "*not found*" in its footprint.

[image]

For example, I want to make the system in the picture above. You already understand the system, if there is no data from the database, `listTile` will say not found in its place.

The `listTile` in my app looks like this when there is no data:

[image]

How can I do that? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just have a check for empty data.

```
if (!snapshot.hasData){
   return myEmptyWidget
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try:

```
items.isEmpty ? const SizedBox() : View(),
```

**Code:**

```
Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 40),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 15,),
            Text("Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),),
            Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.black,),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Solved Tests:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 200,
              child: Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                future: listUpload(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  late List<String?> items;
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  items = [];
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.hasData) {
                  items = snapshot.data as List<String?>;
                  } else {
                    items = [];
                  }
                  return Scrollbar(
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    controller: _scrollContreller,
                    scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                    child: items.isEmpty ? const SizedBox() : ListView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollContreller,
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                items[index].toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
              })),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this issue because you're not fully using the power of the FutureBuilder !
It'll "emit" states during Load and Success/Error. Whenever a state is emitted, it'll redraw the widget.
Therefore, you can return a Widget matching every state of your FutureBuilder like this

```
...
child: FutureBuilder(
    future: listUpload(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      late List<String?> items;
      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return YourLoaderWidget();
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
              ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasData) {
        items = snapshot.data as List<String?>;
        if (items.isEmpty) {
          return YourEmptyWidget();
        } else {
          return YourScrollBar();
        }
      } else {
        return YourErrorWidget();
      }
...
```